# Simple Camera or webcam to take pictures from a fixed location

Tags: camera

I'm looking for a simple camera that has good quality. Requirements are that it can be zoomed in (will be zoomed once only), can be mounted through my own means, so preferably not spherical, and take good quality pictures. It is going to be used to take pictures of tubes with QR codes on top of it, with it being affixed to one position on the machine and zoomed in slightly.

Ideally looking for a good cost to quality ratio for this simple task. Around the $50 area would be excellent.

Comment: Just beware that Webcams open up your firewall to incoming connections (usually from a smart phone) or could log into a data-storage center elsewhere.  Shodan.io can show you how accessible those webcams can be.  If those QR codes are sensitive information it is possible they could get leaked.

Comment: @SDsolar, that's only true for network webcams.  Computer-attached webcams don't do anything to the firewall or network, and don't leak data.

Comment: Are you taking "pictures" or having the video on so you can scan them?

Comment: I'm taking pictures exclusively

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple options that I've found which might be appropriate:

---

Technet C016 ($15)
Manual Focus, Manual LED Brightness, Positive review on amazon for scanning QR codes, 5MP

Logitech C615 ($33)
Folded, flat design, Good autofocus and good movement, 8MP

Logitech C920 ($60)
Same as above; folded, flat design. Higher quality but higher price point, 15MP

Logitech HD Webcam C310 ($29) Good quality, Flat, very flexible